# Evaluate $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i-3 n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Evaluate $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i-3 n}$

Here $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i-3 n}=\frac{1}{1-3 n}+\frac{1}{2-3 n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n-3 n}$.

I tried to make the sum squeezed
between Convergent Sequences, but failed by getting
$\frac{-1}{2} \leq \frac{1}{-3 n+1}+\frac{1}{-3 n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{-3 n+n} \leq \frac{-1}{3}$

Comment: Try to divide both the numerator and the denominator by $n$ and use the definition of integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your sum as

$$\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(a+i\frac{b-a}{n})$$

If $ f $ is integrable or continuous at $ [a,b]$, the limit will be
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx$$

In general, $a=0\;,\;b=1$ and the sum reduces to
$$\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^nf(\frac in)=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\frac in-3}$$

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use an expansion of [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) where $H(n)= \sum \limits_{i=1}^n \frac1n = \log_e(n) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n}+O(n^{-2})$

You then have $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i-3 n} = H(2n-1)-H(3n-1) = \log_e(\frac{2n-1}{3n-1}) + \frac{n}{2(2n-1)(3n-1)}+O(n^{-2})$

and so $\lim\limits _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i-3 n} =\log_e(\frac{2}{3}) =\log_e(2)-\log_e(3)  \approx-0.405$